# Adding View Controllers side by side into a Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

How can i add my existing View Controllers into a Scroll View. I have tried the code below inside 'viewDidLoad' but it didn't work. Thanks

```
let view1 = ViewController6()
        let view2 = ViewController2()
        let view3 = ViewController3()

        contentView.addSubview(view1)
        contentView.addSubview(view2)
        contentView.addSubview(view3)

        self.contentView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.height)
```

Comment: Have a look at container views. The idea is that you create a contentView (UIView), add child UIViewControllers to your current ViewController, then add the child ViewController's view into the content view.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code Here I am doing the exactly thing that you want to achieve.

```
func setupScrollView()
    {
        //loop for 
        for i in 0..<3 {
            //we instantiate our viewController from storyboard
            let news2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsMasterViewController") as! NewsMasterViewController
            //we adjust the frame according
            news2.view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * self.scrollView.frame.size.width + CGFloat(MasterViewController.margin), y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width - CGFloat(MasterViewController.margin * 2), height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
            //we call layoutSubviews for constraints adjustments
            news2.view.layoutSubviews()
            self.addChildViewController(news2)
            //added the view of my viewController "news2" to scrollView
            self.scrollView.addSubview(news2.view)
            news2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            //added the viewController "news2" to my array of viewControllers
            newsMasterViewControllers.append(news2)
        }

        //adjusted contentSize of scrollView according the number of viewControllers added
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 3, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: if removed .didMove method, the scrollView will not move any more. So, great job and thx.